# Uber RideRequestButton Android

Tags: android, uber-api

Is there a way to customize the RideRequestButton provided by Uber API?
I have tried:

```
android:textSize="20sp"
```

in my xml as well as

```
button.setTextsize(20);
```

in my activity.java, but to no success. Is there any other way through which I can customize the text? I want to increase the size of button text. By default text size is small for me.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Yes! You just have to take the [Android SDK's code from GitHub](https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk) and you change it to meet your needs. It's code all the way down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the UserButton object inside the RideRequestButton and customize its properties.

```
UberButton button = (UberButton) requestButton.getChildAt(0);
button.setText(getString("Hello"));
button.setTextSize(10);
```

Comment: thank you for that answer, i had left it unchanged until now.

Comment: Glad to help. I've been trying to find a solution for days!